# Почему в консоль выводится undefined и Неверное значение?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```js
    function factorial(num) {
        let result = 0;
    
        if (typeof(num) == null || String || Object || NaN) {
            return console.log(`Неверное значение: ${num}`);
    
        } else {
            if (num === 1) {
                return result += num;
    
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    result = num * factorial(num - 1);
                    return result;
    
                }
            }
        };
        
        };
    
    console.log(factorial(4));
```

Comment: Потому что console.log() ничего не возвращает, она просто пишет информацию в консоль.

Comment: Так же вот это вот не правильно `typeof(num) == null || String || Object || NaN`

Comment: `typeof` всегда возвращает **строку**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправленная функция расчета факториала

Основные моменты:
Определение типа данных выненсено за пределы **IF**.
Проверка осуществляется на тип данных `number` и что это не **NaN**(`NaN` имеет тип `number`)
Добавлена проверка на отрицательные значения

```js
function factorial(num) {
  if (typeof num !== 'number' || isNaN(num)) {// Проверяем что это число и не NaN
    console.log(`Неверное значение: ${num}`);
    return 0;
  }
  if (num < 1) return 0; // Если отрицательное
  if (num === 1) return num; // Далее считать нечего, возвращаем 1
  return num * factorial(num - 1); // Рекурсивно счичаем значения
};

console.log(factorial(4));
console.log(factorial(-2));
console.log(factorial('r'));
console.log(factorial(NaN));
```

Я добавил вывод 0, если проверка не пройдена, вы можете возвращать любые другие значения.

Comment: очень странный факториал. Нужно было либо использовать цикл, либо рекурсию, как в последнем примере

Comment: @Grundy У автора изначально был так сделано, что рекурсию в цикл положил, ну а первый return собственно цикл прерывает.

Comment: Что бы не смущать никого, лучше оставлю один вариант